# UITabBarController not showing all the size of its contents (UIViewController)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, uitabbarcontroller

My issue is that I cannot get rid of this orange background at the bottom of `UITabBarController`, does anyone have any idea how this can be rid of?

Detail:
I have this `UITabBarController` and when I add a `UIViewController` to it, the `UIViewController` fits to the size within the `UITabBarController` ONLY in iOS 7 of Retina 4 inch screen. However, when I try this in iOS 6 of Retina 4, the background of `UITabBarController` is shown at the bottom of the window in orange.

[image]

I have tried to solve this issue by:

> 1) Recreating the `UITabBarController` and manually setting contentsizeForViewInPopOver
>
> 2) NSLog the frame of `UIViewController` to make sure they are `320x568,960 and 1134` but they both show the same orange (I set the background of `UITabBarController` to be orange to verify)
>
> 3) Enlarged the mapview and the parent view of mapview but no result.

Note: the grey portion at the bottom of the image is all the tabbaritems, but they are not shown for this purpose.

I see no change and cannot figure this out. Can somebody please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research, I found what the cause was.

I had a method called *-(void)showTabBar* on my viewcontroller that was shown, and that set the frame/bounds to a specific frame which was specific for iOS 7 in Retina 4 display!

Now everything is good but thanks to @MrTJ for the hint on *viewDidLayoutSubviews*

Answer (score 1):

Set up 4 auto layout constraints of your map view to the main view of your view controller, one for each side (top, right, bottom, left), all with the value of zero.
[image: Screenshot of Interface Builder]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am not developing on the storyboard as it get complicated as the program gets bigger. Is there a solution equivalent to that programmatically? Thanks!

Comment: You can create layout constraints also programmatically with `constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:` method of `NSLayoutConstraint`. However in your case it might be simpler to change the frame of the map view manually for example from the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of your controller, adding this line: `self.myMapView.frame = self.view.bounds;`